# How to properly run Docker on Google Compute Engine (auto restart)

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine

I was hoping someone could tell me how to properly run Docker on Google Compute Engine..

Right now I use the command:

`docker run --publish 80:8080 --name myContainerName --restart=always MYDOCKERIMAGE`

The problem is that the compute engine often crash (I think?), so every 1-2 days I need to connect (SSH) to the compute engine instance because the Docker container won't restart unless I do so...

Comment: Compute Engine doesn't crash, they have the best live migration technology around the world.

Comment: If the compute engine doesn't crash then how come my Docker container keeps stopping? On my laptop I can keep it running for days without anything happening. I don't mean to question the quality of Compute Engine since I also have a Python project being hosted on Compute Engine using Apache that's working completely fine, running 24/7/365 without any problems.. but how come the Docker container keeps crashing and fail to restart unless I SSH into it?

Comment: Have you looked at the content of the log - by doing a `docker logs <container>`?

Comment: @stephendl The container logs contain nothing except this message: `transport: http2Client.notifyError got notified that the client transport was broken EOF.`  which seems to be repeated every 4 seconds.. could that be causing the crashes because some log file becomes too big?

Comment: Looks like a grpc issue in Go. What version of Go are you using?

Comment: @stephendl go1.7.4 linux/amd64

Comment: That looks like this issue - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/issues/293. When you say that it crashes, can you be more specific please. What makes you think it's crashed?

Comment: @stephendl When I try to access the website then I sometimes get a cloudflare error, I believe it's a 500 internal server error but can't remember. I then SSH into the compute instance, run docker ps and see it's been up for a few seconds, and then the website works again. This usually happens every 1-2 days and it will only work after I SSH and run 'docker ps'.. I remember reading the GitHub issue you linked before, I came to believe it was no problem and could just ignore it (especially since nothing happens whenever the warning occurs)